# Code inside initState not getting executed when using go_router flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

So I have a GroupedRestaurantPage and a SingleRestaurantPage. Here is a minimalistic router code:

```
final router = GoRouter(
 initialLocation:'/',
 routes:[
  GoRoute(
   name:rootRoutName,
   path:'/',
   builder:(context, state) => const HomeScreen(),
   routes:[
    GoRoute(
            name: groupedRestaurantsRouteName,
            path: 'groupedRestaurants/:id',
            builder: (context, state) {
              final id = state.params['id'] ?? '';

              return GroupedRestaurantsScreen(id: id);
            },
    ),
     GoRoute(
                name: singleRestaurantRouteName,
                path: 'restaurants/:id',
                builder: (context, state) {
                  final id = state.params['id'] ?? '';

                  return RestaurantScreen(id: id);
                },
        )
   ]
)
```

Now I have a code inside initState of GroupedRestaurantsPage. It is executed the first time the page loads. Then there is a button that navigates to the single restaurant page. Now when I call context.goNamed(groupedRestaurantsRouteName) from the single restaurant page I want the initState of GroupedRestaurantsPage to be recalled. But that is not getting triggered. How can I solve this.